# calculating confidence intervals for a median in oracle

Tags: oracle, median

I am trying to produce an  oracle sql query which will not only calculate the median age but also the 95% confidence around it. To add a complication need to do it across groups in this case gender
I have a table of people with their age and gender. I want to determine the median age for each group together with its 95% confidence intervals.
My current attempt which fails is as follows.

```
select gender,
       median(age),
       count(*),
       percentile_cont(ROUND((COUNT(*)/2)-1.96*sqrt(COUNT(*))/2)/COUNT(*)) 
         within GROUP (ORDER BY age) lowmedianage,
       percentile_cont(ROUND((COUNT(*)/2)+1.96*sqrt(COUNT(*))/2)/COUNT(*)) 
         within GROUP (ORDER BY age) highmedianage
  from persontable
  group by gender
```

I get an error not a GROUP BY expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the formula from [this book](https://books.google.at/books?id=JPRqOU_fgWUC&pg=PT450&lpg=PT450&dq=r%20confidence%20interval%20with%20median%201.96&source=bl&ots=c5QMLdFBaR&sig=vY7kn7HCrKIgtH5xMyPYqXQW8-g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjpp7j0r5_KAhWJbhQKHSWqBOIQ6AEIJDAB#v=onepage&q=r%20confidence%20interval%20with%20median%201.96&f=false) I'm ending with following query (I'm not sure if you handles the low and high ranges well; my interpretation is that you calculates a range of sequence numbers and you must look up the values from those positions).

```
with tab as 
-- add sequence per group
(
select gender, age,
row_number() over (PARTITION  BY gender order by  gender, age) as seq
from persontable
),
-- get count
N as (select gender, count(*) cnt from persontable group by gender),
-- calculate sequence numbers of the CI
ci_seq as (
select gender,
round(cnt/2 - (1.96 * sqrt(cnt)/2)) r,
round(1 + cnt/2 + (1.96 * sqrt(cnt)/2)) s
from n),
-- calculate median
med as (
select 
  gender,
  median(age) median_age
from  persontable
group by gender),
med2 as (
select med.gender, median_age, r, s
from med 
join ci_seq on med.gender = ci_seq.gender 
)
select gender, median_age,
(select age from tab where seq = r and gender = med2.gender) ci_from,
(select age from tab where seq = s and gender = med2.gender) ci_to
from med2
;
```

Note also, that the formula only approximates the CI. You may also check [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21103/confidence-interval-for-median) for alternative calculations.

Comment: almost works but with my data the upper and lower bounds do not contain the median for males. If I add cnt/2 m, to ci_seq and include (select age from tab where seq=m) median to the final query the median returned for males does not equal the median_age in the same query, it does however match for females. Any ideas?

Comment: The problem with your, really helpful, response is that seq does not return to 1 when the gender changes so when you attempt to match against seq you always look up against the first gender in this case female. Don't know how to get seq to return to 1 when gender changes. This would answer the question

Comment: @Tony - my bad, I tested with one gender only:( I fixed the query, see the added PARTITION BY in `row_number() over (PARTITION  BY gender order by  gender, age) as seq`. This maked the seq wrap on gender. HTH

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you have the function count as a parameter for percentile_cont, which expects a constant there and this constant has to be a part of the group by clause. You could, probably, use a subquery here. Something similar to this:

```
select gender, median(age), count(*),
       percentile_cont(low) within GROUP (ORDER BY age) lowmedianage,
       percentile_cont(high) within GROUP (ORDER BY age) highmedianage
  from (select age, gender,
               ROUND((COUNT(*)/2)-1.96*sqrt(COUNT(*))/2)/COUNT(*) low,
               ROUND((COUNT(*)/2)+1.96*sqrt(COUNT(*))/2)/COUNT(*) high
          from persontable
         group by age, gender)
 group by gender, low, high
```